# Android: post photo on Instagram and track likes and comments

Tags: android, instagram, instagram-api

In my android app , I want to post a photo to Instagram using share intent. 
After posting photo I need to know , media-id for that image / video. 
Later I want to get likes and comments for that specific media from Instagram. Once media-id is known this can be done using api . However is there a good way to get media-id of image or video when you post using share intent ?